# SQL Server 2017 Linux Is backup to URL supported in

Tags: sql-server, linux, backup

I've setup SQL Server 2017 (Web Edition) on Ubuntu 16.04 and everything seems to be working ok, with the exception of backups to Azure blob.  I create a credential in Sql Server, then try to do a backup to URL, and I get the following error:

> Msg 3292, Level 16, State 6, Line 9
>   A failure occurred while attempting to execute Backup or Restore with a URL device specified. Consult the operating system error log for details.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

When I check my server logs, I see this:

> Feb  4 16:45:29  sqlservr[1137]: #015BackupToUrl: couldn't load process Error Code:  80070002

When I run through the *exact* same steps on my local db (on Windows), it runs just fine.

Question: is backup to URL not supported on Linux?  The server log is saying it couldn't load the process BackupToURL, is this something that needs to be installed as a separate package?

Comment: Same for me. Did you ever get it working on Linux

Comment: No, I just gave up on it and persisted the back-ups elsewhere..

Comment: I ran into this problem. I solved it by using a SAS - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-ver15#SAS